window react-native android yarn start error , SSL error/Check comments
The development environment is local.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

version up down (java node npm gradle)
ssl input

I am setting up the React Native Cli version locally, but various SSL-related errors occur. So if a problem arises to resolve it, I will leave it in the comments. If you know, I would appreciate your help.

npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server html-webpack-plugin --save-dev

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I did get similar error when i run npx react-native run-android. It turns out that i was connected to VPN. When I close the VPN connection it worked.
